# How do I change a ModernUI games permissions to update Xbox Account Information?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

When you first use an Xbox enabled game from the Store, it first asks for permission to modify your Xbox Account Information, stating that you can change this from the account settings.

Which account settings do I need to use to change this permission?

The settings in the games themselves don't include this (usually it's just "Notifications" in the permissions tab and "This application can use your internet connection").

Checking in the Games app, there's no list of apps that can interact with Xbox account, and I also can't find anything in the xbox.com account area.

The behaviour is consistent across computers - so for an account that has denied access on one machine, that state is replicated to other machines for the same game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the main problem (being unable to sign-in) was caused by the fact that the games were linked to the parent's account in the store when they were installed. The parent needs to remain signed in to the store, then the child can sign in with their Xbox Live account.

It looks like you can **revoke** permissions after allowing them from the Web page.

From http://account.live.com/permissions/ select "Manage your accounts":

[image: Manage account permissions]

From there you can see a list of all the apps you've given access to various elements of your account:

[image: Choose an app]

And then you can click through and revoke the XBox Live Account permissions:

[image: Remove permissions]

I assume that if an app had multiple permissions you could remove individual ones, or just use the "Remove [App Name]" button to revoke the lot.

I've not found an obvious way to allow an app to access this information if you've previously denied it access from within the app.